# Turning client-server application going into a web based

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

In my company, they are about to automate the appliation. I have got some rough idea about webdriver. So, my question is before the application is not on to the browser, whether we can able to test using selenium webdriver? Please answer..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Selenium WebDriver is an API for automating browsers.  So if your application is not (or not yet) a browser application, then Selenium won't be able to help.